# Why send_keys() method is not working. `element not interactable`

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
inpt1 =ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='DraftEditor-editorContainer']")))
print(len(inpt1))
inpt1.send_keys('hello')
```

Using the code from above, I got `1` output for `length` of `inpt1` but for send_keys I am getting the following error: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

I want to send keys to that section surrounded by the yellow line.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code with action chain, ElementNotInteractableException is thrown when element present on the HTML DOM, but its not in a state that can be interacted with. :

```
    inpt1 =ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='DraftEditor-editorContainer']")))
    print(len(inpt1))
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(inpt1).send_keys('hello').perform()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer and hit upvote button from your endfrom your end.